# Item_scraped_count doesn't appear on terminal screen in Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am just a new learner. This happened when i tried to follow the instruction that was given, but result showed that there is no data scrapped.

```
import scrapy



class BookspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bookspider'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        book = response.css('article.product_pod')

        for boks in book:
            yield{
                'name':boks.css('h3 a::text').get(),
                'price':boks.css('.product_price .price_color::text').get(),
                'url': boks.css('h3 a').attrib['href'],
            }
```

I don't know why. i just checked if the html somehow changed after a while in the website, but nothing has been changed so far.

Comment: how are you executing the code?